# Command line parameter is being ignored

Tags: java, command-line

When I run below class via command line using :

```
java TestConnection www.google.com&test
```

the output is :

```
Testing www.google.com
```

So the everything after the & is being ignored.

If I pass the argument into the main method using Eclipse then the argument is read correctly.

The class :

```
public class TestConnection {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("Testing "+args[0]);
    }

}
```

How can I grab the entry argument string and not have everything after the & chopped off ? Why does this occur ?

Comment: You need to escape the '&' character in the command line... This a issue of dispatching the actual argument... Nothing wrong with the actual java code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `&` is being interpreted by the shell.
You can protect your arguments from the shell by surrounding them with quotes:

```
java TestConnection "www.google.com&test"
```